# Bibliography code does not run?

Tags: pdftex, bibtex

Wondering why the reference

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Reference}
```

does not appear in my pdf when I compile it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You've provided no useful details in your post. How do you expect anyone to be able to answer without them? Mind-reading? Throwing out wild guesses hoping one sticks? If you want help here, you need to provide details. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: you need to run bibtex to generate a bibliography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discuss the situation we need a minimal working example (MWE) you did not add to your question.  Let us start with the following one, copy it to your computer and name it `mwe.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

Text~\cite{adams} % citing one bib entry % <============================
\nocite{*}   % all not cited bib entrys are shown in bibliography ...
\bibliographystyle{plain} % <===========================================
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use file created by filecontents ...

\end{document}
```

Package `filecontents` is only used to have a bib file and the TeX code together in one compilable MWE.

To get a printed bibliography you need `\cite{key}` to cite the bib entry `key`, like:

```
Text~\cite{adams} % citing one bib entry % <============================
```

or use `\nocite{*}` to get **all** not cited bib entrys printed in your bibliography.

The bibliography style `plain` defines the layout of the printed bibliography.
\nocite{*}   % all not cited bib entrys are shown in bibliography ...

To get the MWE compiled you need to follow the compiling chain (open your terminal/console and type the following commands):

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

to compile `mwe.tex` and get file `mwe.aux` we need for the next step:

```
bibtex mwe.aux
```

which results in a file `mwe.bbl` containing the bibliography. Now type

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

to get the final document like this:

[image: bibliography]

Check the documentation of your used editor how to start `pdflatex` and `bibtex` with it.

Comment: Why are you answering the same unclear questions again and again and again? Before it is even clear where tge provlem is?

Answer (score 1):

How does your `Reference.bib` looks like?

```
\bibliography{Reference}
Imports the BibTeX file "Reference.bib" to display the bibliography.
To import several .bib files just write them comma-separated inside
the braces, the file extension is not necessary.
```

example:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

run bibtex:

```
pdflatex document.tex
bibtex Reference
pdflatex document.tex
pdflatex document.tex
```

references:

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex
https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex

Comment: I've copied that code and pasted it into a TeX document but there is still no reference

Comment: @TheSimpliFire -- that code isn't meant to be pasted into a tex document.  it consists of four commands to be processed from the command line.